# SQL query to show most recent row in table with data, or null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB table structure with rows that are filled through an interview process, and each "customer" can go through the interview process multiple times, even on the same day. The table structure looks like this:

```
Table: Customers
-------------
CustomerId
...

Table: Questions
-------------
QuestionId | QuestionText
0          | Last Location?
1          | Last Color?
2          | Last Food?
3          | Last Drink?

Table: Answers
-------------
Id | CustomerId | QuestionId | AnswerText | Created_On
1    0            0            Chicago      08/15/2017 7:56:34 AM
2    0            0            Laramie      08/16/2017 9:27:23 AM
3    0            0            Null         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
4    0            1            Null         08/15/2017 7:56:34 AM
5    0            1            Green        08/16/2017 9:27:23 AM
6    0            1            Blue         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
7    0            2            Pizza        08/15/2017 7:56:34 AM
8    0            2            Null         08/16/2017 9:27:23 AM
9    0            2            Null         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
10   0            3            Null         08/15/2017 7:56:34 AM
11   0            3            Null         08/16/2017 9:27:23 AM
12   0            3            Null         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
```

Currently we display the "last interview" by querying the data for the most recent timestamp for each question and showing the result, whether it has a value or is null, like this:

```
LastAnswer_QueryResult
-------------
Id | CustomerId | QuestionId | AnswerText | Created_On
3    0            0            Null         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
6    0            1            Blue         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
9    0            2            Null         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
12   0            3            Null         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
```

The new requirement is to show the most recent answer for each question with a value, or null if the question has never been answered. If I could get the query right the result for the sample data above would look like:

```
MostRecentAnswer_QueryResult
Id | CustomerId | QuestionId | AnswerText | Created_On
2    0            0            Laramie      08/16/2017 9:27:23 AM
6    0            1            Blue         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
7    0            2            Pizza        08/15/2017 7:56:34 AM
12   0            3            Null         08/17/2017 6:34:56 AM
```

So far the best approach I can come up with is to insert the oldest rows into a temp table, then in a loop, update the values if they exist with a newer timestamp. Then when done, update any null values with the most recent timestamp. Is there a way I can accomplish this without looping and inserting into a temp table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions to the rescue! Partition by `customerid` and `questionid`, and assign a `row_number()` to rows in each partition. If we didn't have to worry about `answertext is null`, we would simply order by `created_on desc`.

To deal with `null`, we first order by whether `answertext` is not null vs. it is null. This is done easily with a `case` expression (see below).

Then in an outer query we select the rows where the `row_number` is 1 (within every combination of `customerid` and `questionid`).

```
select id, customerid, questionid, answertext, ts
from   (
         select id, customerid, questionid, answertext, ts,
                row_number() over ( partition by customerid, questionid
                                        order by case when answertext is not null
                                                      then 0 end,
                                                 created_on desc
                                  ) as rn
         from   answers
       )
where  rn = 1
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the note about "timestamp" - I had to obfuscate the actual column names and forgot it was a reserved word. Fixed in the sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
select MAX(a.id) ID, a.CustomerId , q.QuestionId,LISTAGG(AnswerText,' * ')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AnswerText, max(a.Created_On) Created_On
    from Questions q
    left join Answers a
    on a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
    where a.AnswerText is not null
    group by a.CustomerId , q.QuestionId 
    UNION ALL 
    select MAX(a.id) ID, a.CustomerId , q.QuestionId ,LISTAGG(AnswerText,' *')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AnswerText, max(a.Created_On) Created_On
     from Questions q
    left join Answers a
    on a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
    where a.AnswerText is  null AND
    Q.QuestionId NOT IN(
         select q.QuestionId
         from Questions q
      left join Answers a
      on a.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
      where a.AnswerText is not null
      group by a.CustomerId , q.QuestionId
    )
    group by a.CustomerId , q.QuestionId 
    ORDER BY QuestionId
```

After that, you will get the fist name AnswerText between '*'